# Trying to find out how to add the icons back on my home screen it is an Android phone

Tags: app-icons

I accidentally delated the icons on my Android phone, how can I add them back.

Comment: Did the icons disappear from the app drawer or the desktop? What is your phone model/Android version? Please [edit your question](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/197767/edit) and add these details.

Comment: @Zackary the title suggests OP cleared them from the home screen. // Beverly: If you open your app drawer (usually a circle menu with 6 or 9 dots arranged as rectangle, located at the very bottom of your home screen), check for an icon you wish to have on your homescreen, and long-press (aka "tap-and-hold") it, you can "drop" it on the homescreen. Have you tried that already?

Comment: @Izzy I posted my answer because it does suggest the icons were deleted from the desktop (not the app drawer).

Comment: @Zackary yes, but how does one "right press"? Never heard that :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple answer, but go to the "Apps" screen (the button with several dots on it) and right press (touch and hold) the icon you want. Then, position it where you want on the screen and release.

You can also create folders by putting an app icon on top of another and widgets by long pressing the desktop > Widgets.

If you erased the icons on a third-party launcher (e.g. Nova Launcher) and have the same config on your stock launcher (or a backup), you can go to (right press) > Settings > Backup & import settings > Import from another launcher (or Import backup if you have a backup).